# Adding view to NativeScript ActionBar breaks navigation

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationbar, nativescript

I'm trying to implement an `<ActionBar>` that starts off with a transparent background then, as the page is scrolled a background colour is faded in.

I've made some progress with this by creating a new `UIView` and adding it to the navigationbar. Then setting the background colour on this view based on the current scroll position.

Page:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded" backgroundSpanUnderStatusBar="true">

<Page.actionBar>
    <ActionBar title="Page two">
        <NavigationButton text="Go Back" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_back" tap="tapGoBack"/>
    </ActionBar>
</Page.actionBar>

<ScrollView id="scrollView" style="margin-top: -64" backgroundColor="salmon">

    <StackLayout style="height: 800">
        <Image src="~/img/enjoying-a-tasty-burger-picjumbo-com.jpg" />
    </StackLayout>

</ScrollView>
</Page>
```

Codebehind:

```
var frameModule = require("ui/frame");

exports.pageLoaded = function(args) {
    var page = args.object;

    if (page.ios) {

        var controller = frameModule.topmost().ios.controller;

        /**
         * Make ActionBar background transparent
         */
        var navBar = controller.navigationBar;
        navBar.shadowImage = new UIImage();
        navBar.setBackgroundImageForBarMetrics(new UIImage, UIBarMetrics.UIBarMetricsDefault);

        /**
         * Add custom view to navBar
         */
        var navBounds = navBar.bounds;
        var myView = UIView.alloc().init();
        myView.frame = {
            origin: { x: navBounds.origin.x, y: navBounds.origin.y - 20 },
            size: { width: navBounds.size.width, height: navBounds.size.height + 20 }
        };
        myView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        navBar.addSubview(myView);

        navBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorWithRedGreenBlueAlpha(0.20, 0.20, 0.20, 0.0);
        navBar.sendSubviewToBack(myView);

        /**
         * Fade in myView on scroll
         */
        var scrollView = page.getViewById("scrollView");
        scrollView.on('scroll', function(args){
            var offset = args.object.verticalOffset;
            myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorWithRedGreenBlueAlpha(0.20, 0.20, 0.20, (offset-50)/50);
        });

    }

}


exports.tapGoBack = function() {
    frameModule.topmost().goBack();
}
```

Works great - except now I am unable to use the `NavigationButton`.

I can see from Xcode's view debugger that the `UIView` is behind the `<NavigationButton>` yet I can not interact with it.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea why adding a `UIView` to the `NavigationBar` would break the `NavigationButton`?

There is an animated gif (too large to upload here) [here](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/1102402/21938113/d02878a2-d9b1-11e6-8503-e99149f73827.gif) showing the problem and some further info in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3471).

There is a sample project hosted on [GitHub here](https://github.com/3rror404/actionbar-test) if anyone wants to play along.

```
┌──────────────────┬─────────────────┬────────────────┬───────────────┐
│ Component        │ Current version │ Latest version │ Information   │
│ nativescript     │ 2.4.2           │ 2.4.2          │ Up to date    │
│ tns-core-modules │ 2.4.4           │ 2.4.4          │ Up to date    │
│ tns-android      │                 │ 2.4.1          │ Not installed │
│ tns-ios          │ 2.4.0           │ 2.4.0          │ Up to date    │
└──────────────────┴─────────────────┴────────────────┴───────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just disable the **[userInteractionEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622577-userinteractionenabled)** for ***myView*** and you are good to go!

```
...
myView.userInteractionEnabled = false;
navBar.addSubview(myView);
...
```

Comment: @NickLiev I'd kiss you if I could. Now I just need to figure out how to remove the UIView on navigatedFrom 0_0. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Tumip you can tag your view like this `myView.tag = 17`

Comment: and then to remove it in `navigatingFrom` (in your second-page) do `var myView = navBar.viewWithTag(17);
 myView.removeFromSuperview();`

Comment: Here is the full test but in TS https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Issues-2017/tree/master/NativeScript/issue_3471/issue_3471

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. You've really set me on the right track here.