# Transparent ActionBar: using NativeScript in combination with Angular

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-angular

Hi Nativescript Community,

I can`t get the transparency to work on the ActionBar using Nativescript in combination with Angular. I have found serval topics like this one, but no one has a working example using Angular. Would somebody like to send me a working example of a transparent ActionBar background using Angular?
Finally i would like to be able to change the transparency upon scrolling.

Some relevant topics (but without working angular example):

1. https://github.com/3rror404/ns-fading-actionbar
2. [Adding view to NativeScript ActionBar breaks navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41699116/adding-view-to-nativescript-actionbar-breaks-navigation)
3. https://www.nativescript.org/blog/how-to-match-a-nativescript-actionbar-s-color-on-ios
4. https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/scrolling-behind-transparent-actionbar/2133
5. https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/tranparent-action-bar/3413
6. https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2669

Regards,

Timber

Comment: I swear this is making me go crazy, I've looked at every link and article, it still is translucent. I'm glad I'm not the only one who is struggling with this.

Comment: Well apparently no one seems to have the correct answer to this, multiple view but no answers:(

Comment: I think you should hide the action bar as shown in example https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=Y4fVGt&v=16 by which the action bar would be transparent. You can customise the top of the page to have any buttons or labels.

Answer (score 0):

You can use anything as a action-bar. Put a label on top 7% of a gridlayout and there you go. I don't know if actionbar tools would work or not but you can try it out.

Comment: Does this work with actionbar buttons? I have the same problem now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for iOS.

```js
import { topmost, Color } from "tns-core-modules/ui/frame";

declare let UIBarMetrics, UIBarStyle, UIImage;

makeActionBarTransparent() : void {
    let navbar = topmost().ios.controller.navigationBar;
    navbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.BlackTranslucent;
    navbar.setBackgroundImageForBarMetrics(UIImage.new(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
    navbar.shadowImage = UIImage.new();
    navbar.translucent = true;
    navbar.tintColor = new Color('white').ios;
}
```

But it seems that when you modify the action bar in a page, action bar is modified in other pages too. If this is not the desired behavior for you, you can hide the action bar and use custom elements. For example, create a transparent stack-layout with action icons on it.

You can hide the actionbar like this:

```js
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";

constructor(
    private page : Page
) {}

ngAfterViewInit() : void {
    this.page.actionBarHidden = true;
}
```